# Responding request handlers with non-blocking operations on Node.js

Tags: node.js

i'm learning Node.js with Node Beginner Book.
I'm stuck when I try to manage the requests with non-blocking operations.

If I go to localhost:8888 it returns the list of files, but if I go to localhost:8888/start or /upload it return 404 not found. Why?

index.js

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");
var handle = {};
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;
server.start(router.route,handle);
```

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
function start(route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

   route(handle, pathname, response);
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

requestHandlers.js

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

function start(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
    exec("ls -lah", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(stdout);
        response.end();
    });
}

function upload(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello Upload");
    response.end();
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

router.js

```
function route(handle, pathname, response) {
   console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
   if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
       handle[pathname](response);
   } else {
      console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
      response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write("404 Not found");
     response.end();
   }
 }

 exports.route = route;
```

Answer (score 2):

it's the handler keys in your index.js, they should be:

```
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;
```

I've tested this and it's definitely the problem

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the handler keys all start with "/" ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `response` as an argument to the `exec` call, like this:

```
function start(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
    exec("ls -lah", response, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        //          ^^^^^^^^
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(stdout);
        response.end();
    });
}
```